# Subresource integrity and cache busting techniques in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css, caching, subresource-integrity

I'd like to implement [**Subresource Integrity**](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/) and **cache busting** for static assets such as stylesheets and JavaScript files in my application. Currently I use PHP with Twig templates.

I know there are many tools out there to generate hashes for all the JS and CSS files but I am looking for how to implement the hashes into the `<script>` and `<link>` tags for hundreds of files.

[This blog post](https://adactio.com/journal/8504) described most of what I'm trying to do, however the author only covers cache busting and uses a static timestamp in the file name that he changes manually every time. Using a build tool to programatically generate that timestamp isn't difficult either but with SRI the value is a hash, which is *different for every file*.

For example, a snippet of `header.html.twig`:

```
<!-- cdn requests -->

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'
    integrity='sha384-8gBf6Y4YYq7Jx97PIqmTwLPin4hxIzQw5aDmUg/DDhul9fFpbbLcLh3nTIIDJKhx'
    crossorigin='anonymous'></script>

<!-- same-origin requests -->

<script src='foo.1a516fba.min.js' 
    integrity='sha384-GlFvui4Sp4wfY6+P13kcTmnzUjsV78g61ejffDbQ1QMyqL3lVzFZhGqawasU4Vg+'></script>
<script src='bar.faf315f3.min.js'
    integrity='sha384-+vMV8w6Qc43sECfhc+5+vUA7Sg4NtwVr1J8+LNNROMdHS5tXrqGWSSebmORC6O86'></script>
```

Changing the `src`/`href` and `integrity` attributes every time is not a sane approach.

I could write a Twig function that calls a PHP function to hash the file every time and it may work on OK on dev but that seems awfully computationally expensive.

What is a feasible approach to this?

Comment: Does SRI hash change if a script has been injected using HTACCESS file (i.e. footer)?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: There is no feasible approach because this is not a proper application of Subresource Integrity.

According to [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/) the integrity attribute is:

> ...a mechanism by which user agents may verify that a fetched resource has been delivered without unexpected manipulation

It was introduced because these days lots of pages are fetching their CSS and JS scripts from CDNs like you are and if a hacker were ever to gain control of a CDN they could wreak an extraordinary amount of havoc across thousands of websites by injecting malicious code into the resources delivered!

Imagine if every version of jQuery delivered by `code.jquery.com` or `ajax.googleapis.com` suddenly contained malicious code! How many sites would be affected? Scary.

By providing the agent (browser) with an integrity hash that the contents of the fetched resource should be compared against, you are ensuring the agent only continues to execute the code if it gets exactly what you told it to expect. If it's different, don't trust it!

In the case of the resources in *your* application, I assume they exist on the same server so there is no middle route to intercept. If a hacker gains control of your server and injects malicious code in the JS scripts, they could just as easily rehash the contents and change the integrity attribute in your HTML as well. Subresource Integrity offers no additional security check.

**But...**

Just for the sport of solving what is quite a fun problem I would suggest if you wanted to dynamically generate the hash for the `integrity` attribute:

Use Gulp (my personal preference) to concatenate, minify and thumbprint the filename of your resource. Read the contents of the generated file using `gulp.src('bar.*.min.js')`. Use the [NPM sha1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha1) package to create the hash as a variable and finally maybe use [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) to change the src attribute and then [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) to write the `integrity` attribute too. Some flow like that is what I would go for :-)

I hope that answers your question.